# Bash - Troubling result with IF [..] || [..]

Tags: bash, if-statement

I can seem to see why this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ $# -ne 2 ]; then 
# Should run if there are either 1 or 2 options specified
  echo "usage: ${0##*/} <username>"
  exit
fi
```

When testing to see if it works:

```
root@ubuntu:~# testing.sh optionone optiontwo
...Correct output...
root@ubuntu:~# testing.sh optionone
usage: testing.sh <username>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are executing 2 commands in:

```
[ $# -ne 1 ] || [ $# -ne 2 ]
```

`[ $# -ne 1 ]` is a 1st command, and the `[ $# -ne 2 ]` command is executed only if the previous has a non-zero error code as of the `||` shell operator.

In your case, it is not important, but in the case bellow, it is:

```
[ $? -eq 0 ] || [ $? -eq 1 ]
```

The 2nd command will always be true, as the 2nd `$?` is the return code of `[ $? -eq 0 ]`.  You can test it with the lines bellow that will print `true` twice:

```
function f() { return $1; }
f 1
{ [ $? -eq 0 ] || [ $? -eq 1 ]; } && echo "true"
f 2
{ [ $? -eq 0 ] || [ $? -eq 1 ]; } && echo "true"
```

The correct way to execute a `or` in a single command is:

```
[ $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 1 ]
```

This way, those bellow only print `true` once:

```
function f() { return $1; }
f 1
{ [ $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 1 ]; } && echo "true"
f 2
{ [ $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 1 ]; } && echo "true"
```

And concerning your original question, kev has already point out that there was a logic error in your test.  The negative of `[ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2 ]` is `NOT [ $# -eq 1 ] && NOT [ $# -eq 2 ]` and this becomes `[ $# -ne 1 ] && [ $# -ne 2 ]` or in a single command:

```
[ $# -ne 1 -a $# -ne 2 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the boolean logic:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ] && [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
```

Or

```
if ! ( [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2 ] ); then
```

BTW, you can use `Shell-Arithmetic` [`((...))`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

```
if (( $#!=1 && $#!=2 )); then
```

Comment: if 2 is true then 1 returns false, and vice versa, so it has to be or

Comment: Note that using parentheses, you are starting a subshell.  This `function f() { a=hello; ! ( a=world && { [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2 ]; } ) && echo $a; }; f a b c` will print `hello` and this `function f() { a=hello; ! { a=world && { [ $# -eq 1 ] || [ $# -eq 2 ]; } } && echo $a; }; f a b c` will print `world`.

Comment: @King Please just _try/test_ the `&&` thing.

Comment: I've tested them all but none of them work, they only allow me to have 0 options selected, I've had to result to just using `if [ $1 ] then #true is good# else 
  echo "usage: ${0##*/} <username>"
I'm probably doing something wrong since everyone else expects these to work?
  exit
fi`

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is to switch out the `-ne` comparison operator for `-lt` and `-gt` (*less than* and *greater than)* for the conditional statement.  Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Should run if there are either 1 or 2 options specified
if [ $# -lt 1 ] || [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: ${0##*/} <username>"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: It dosen't work at all with that code..
`root@ubuntu:~# testing.sh hello goodbye
usage: testing.sh <username>
root@ubuntu:~# testing.sh hello
usage: testing.sh <username>
`

Comment: I've resulted to just using `if [ ${1} ] then echo "" else ... exit ...`

Comment: Either way... as long as you are getting the result you need, here;